# check if else in eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a piece of code:

```
$filter = PriceSubscription::select('id', 'name', 'age', 'address')
          ->where('id', 'like', '%' . $id . '%')
          ->where('name', $name)
          ->where('age', 'like', '%' . $age . '%')
          ->orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
          ->get()->toArray();
```

I want to check `if/else` right inside `where`.
Example:

```
if (!empty($id)) {
   ->where('id', 'like', '%' . $id . '%');
}
```

Please give me ideas.

Comment: can you elaborate what you want to check using if else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `when`

```
$filter = PriceSubscription::select('id', 'name', 'age', 'address')
        ->when(!empty($id),function ($query)use($id){
            $query->where('id', 'like', '%' . $id . '%');
        })
       ->where('name', $name)
        ->where('age', 'like', '%' . $age . '%')
        ->orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

or you can use where callback

```
$filter = PriceSubscription::select('id', 'name', 'age', 'address')
            ->where(function ($query)use($id){
                if(!empty($id)){
                    $query->where('id', 'like', '%' . $id . '%');
                }
                
            })
            ->where('name', $name)
            ->where('age', 'like', '%' . $age . '%')
            ->orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
            ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks bro..You have helped me a lot with my work !

Answer (score 4):

You can either break out of your method chain:

```
$filter = PriceSubscription::select('id', 'name', 'age', 'address');
if (!empty($id)) {
   $filter->where('id', 'like', '%' . $id . '%');
}
          $filter->where('name', $name)
          ->where('age', 'like', '%' . $age . '%')
          ->orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
          ->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

If use laravel version >= 5.2 You can write  code simple:

```
$conditions = [  
   ['name',  '=', $name], 
   ['age',  'like', "%$age%"]
 ];
if (!empty($id)) {
   array_push($conditions, ['id', 'like', "%$id%"]);
}
PriceSubscription::select('id', 'name', 'age', 'address')
->where($conditions)
->orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
->get()->toArray();
```